# EADDRINUSE error for opening websocket on different path but same port in nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am creating a multiroom chat application based on ws websockets in nodejs. I can make single chatroom work but while creating second room, I get EADDRINUSE error. The error is because I already have the websocket port in use for first room. How can I create second room on same port with different path.

For example:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
a = new WebSocketServer({port:8080, path:'/a'}), 
b = new WebSocketServer({port:8080, path:'/b'});
```

This give error : Error: listen EADDRINUSE 8080

Thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that each `WebSocketServer` adds a new listener for the upgrade event on the HTTP server and when that event is emitted, `handleUpgrade` is called on all servers.
This is because path validation closed the connection on path [mismatch](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/0cfa5cc94d50bebd6f85b78ec1094dd9a7a17d62/lib/WebSocketServer.js#L171).

they way you're using, for different paths on same port for web-sockets is not a good idea because in your case a connection to `something.com/a` would first be established on `a` and then closed by `b` as they both write on the same socket.

In order to have multiple WebSocket servers and only one shared HTTP server, a developer could use something like this:

```
const wss1 = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });
const wss2 = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });
const server = http.createServer();

server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
  const pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

  if (pathname === '/a') {
    wss1.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
      wss1.emit('connection', ws);
    });
  } else if (pathname === '/b') {
    wss2.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
      wss2.emit('connection', ws);
    });
  } else {
    socket.destroy();
  }
});
```

Comment: What will happen if the number of different path(chat room) is dynamic. in this example I just mentioned two chat room, what happens if I have multiple path on same websocket port?

Comment: I don't think if that can be real life problem (having dynamic chat rooms) as you'll always know of what and how many chat rooms you support for your application. And you can always use `if` or `switch` to emit on that connections. Right ? make sense ?